# How do I add unique content to each tab in an Android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make an app that has three tabs, each with different but linked content. Currently, I want some features to appear on one tab but not on another. For example, I would like a SeekBar to be displayed on only one of the tabs. But, currently, it is displayed for all of them.

I greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Have you used xml (or) java code to populate view? any specific reason not to use individual activity? as per android, it is recommended to use individual activity right?

Comment: @thinksteep, I'm new to android so forgive my simplistic response. Each does does have its own class that extends Tab Activity.Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, then why you  are having shared content? may be diiferent view xml will resolve the issue right? If you can post what you have that will great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to dynamically add content to the [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html). You will be able to add different tabs to the TabActivity once it is created based on a variable. Here is an example ...

```
TabHost host = findViewById(R.id.my_tabhost);
boolean boo = true; //Variable that will decide what tabs to add
host.setup(); //Need to call before adding tabs
if (boo)
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Hello").setIndicator("Hello").setContent(new Intent(this, HelloActivity.class)));
else
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Goodbye").setIndicator("Goodbye").setContent(new Intent(this, GoodbyeActivity.class));
```

This way the tabs will be different if `boo` is `true` or if boo is false. Then you can add your content to `HelloActivity` and `GoodbyeActivity`.

Comment: that's some cool code and thank you for responding but it's quite what I was asking. I want to make three tabs, each of which have different content. As I understand it, the Intents for each Tab should be different to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes. The intent tells the tabhost which activity will handle that tab. So when the user clicks on the Hello tab, HelloActivity will be used to fill the content. Same goes for the Goodbye Tab. If this doesn't answer your question please explain more.